# Differences in execution of console application directly from .exe vs executed via task schedule?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, exception, console-application, excel-2003

im working on a Window server 2008, in this server i developed a vb.net 2008 console application that open a excel 2003 file and use its contents to create a xml file, so i have two situations:
**1. Differences in execution of the program:** if i run the application from the Visual Studio or directly from the executable it open  and process the excel without problems but if i configured a task on the windows task scheduler or in the adtempus that execute this program its failed and throws this exception: 
*Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC-   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
   at .Module1.convertExcelToXmlFile(String excelFile)*

i have read alot about this exception, but at the moment im unable to resolved, so I want to know how this program can execute correctly from Visual Studio or directly from the execute but failed when its execute on a task if both situations are in the same server? is there a way to fix this behavior?

2. In the console application when i open the excel file with the open method, the file in excel appears for a few seconds then it closed, is there a way to access the excel file contents but that the file dont show in Ms Excel?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using Office Interop in an unattended process.

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.
>
> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=257757

There are a number of products that will manipulate Excel docs and run correctly unattended.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Excel file you're trying to open on the network?

If so, the problem is most likely because your Task Scheduler service and any jobs it runs are (by default) running under the local SYSTEM account, which is prohibited from network access.

If you change the task to run under a different account (say, for example, a domain account that you have given privileges for the remote fileshare). (Note that this change may effect how other scheduled tasks run, so you'll want to be quite sure of the permissions needed.)

Comment: hi, the file is located in the same server where im running the program in both ways directly from visual studio and in the task schedule or adtempus

Comment: Well, that rules out my answer above :) How about other common causes of "file not found"-type errors, such as: are you using full paths instead of relative (since the task may be executing from a different working directory)? or, are there any quotes missing in file paths with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have not figured it out yet, the most-likely resolution which worked for me can be found at this URL :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64?forum=innovateonoffice

If your server is a 64-bit one, create a folder named 'Desktop' in the below mentioned path i.e. *C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop*

If your server is a 32-bit one, please make this folder *C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop*